# JS Как найти значение по ключу

Tags: javascript, json, объекты

есть вот такой код

```js
var dict = {
  "bânk": {
    "~": "банка",
  },
  "hostol": {
    "~": "гостиница",
    "~o": "гостиничный"
  }
}
```

И нужно чтобы я ввёл **гостиничный** и мне вернулось что это слова находиться в объекте **hostol** и находится под ключом **~o**
я вообще не представляю как это сделать, как искать по такой сложной структуре в интернете не нашёл.

Comment: "чу", "щу" - пиши с буквой "у"

Answer (score 0):

```
function findObjectProperty(obj, value) {
  let result = {};
  for (let item in obj) {
      for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj[item])) {
          if (val === value) {
            result.findObject = item;
            result.findProperty = key
          }
      }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(result)
```

}

```
findObjectProperty(dict, "гостиничный");
```

Результат в виде {"findObject":"hostol","findProperty":"~o"}

Answer (score -2):

```js
function findKeyByValue(dict, target) {
  let found = undefined; // здесь храним найденное значение. Изначально его нет, поэтому undefined

  return (function findKeyByValue(dict, target) { // (*) переопределяем функцию внутри, чтобы `found` не загрязнял глобальную область видимости
    if (found) return found; // если у found появилось значение, то его и возвращаем

    Object.entries(dict).forEach(([key, entry]) => { // для каждой пары клююч-значение у dict
      if (typeof entry === "object") { // если тип значения - объект
        found = findKeyByValue(entry, target); // то рекурсивно производим те же действия для этого объекта (начиная со строчки (*))
      } else { // если нет
        if (entry === target) { // то сравниваем искомое значение с текущим
          found = key; // сохраняем его в found, если они равны и выходим
          return;
        }
      }
    });

    return found; // возвращаем то, что удалось найти.
  })(dict, target);
}

const dict = { // подобъекты поменяны местами
  hostol: {
    "~": "гостиница",
    "~o": "гостиничный",
  },
  bânk: {
    "~": "банка",
  },
};

console.log(findKeyByValue(dict, "гостиничный"));
```

Comment: "Как-то так." - не так.

Comment: @Igor поправите? Ошибка в алгоритме?

Comment: В примере из вопроса этот псевдокод ничего не найдет.

Comment: Тонкий момент в рекурсии - когда из нее выходить.

Comment: @smellyshovel
 `Object.entries(dict).forEach([key, value] => {/* implementation */})` данный код не подходит т.к известно только значение, а ключ не известен. Конечно может это я не правильно понял.

Comment: @Igor Поправил. Протестировал. Работает.

Comment: @TiM-SyStEm да, это вы неправильно поняли. Обновил псевдокод.

Comment: Теперь поменяйте местами подобъекты в примере из вопроса.

Comment: @smellyshovel
`для каждой пары ключ-значение объекта `dict`:` можете пожалуйста написать как эта строчка выглядит на js

Comment: @Igor справедливо :D Сейчас добъем

Comment: Поправил. Не знаю, как некоторые вещи в псевдокоде описать, поэтому прикладываю готовый код на JS.